# Unable to push to git repository on my server

Tags: git, github, ssh

I want to have two git repositories on my server. One of them belongs to someone else. I copy their ssh keys onto my account:

```
sudo cp /home/otheruser/.ssh/id_rsa id_rsa
sudo cp /home/otheruser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub id_rsa.pub
git clone git@github.com:otheruser/Gateway.git
git remote show origin
* remote origin
Fetch URL: git@github.com:otheruser/Gateway.git
Push  URL: git@github.com:otheruser/Gateway.git
HEAD branch: master
Remote branches:
...
```

Now I want to copy some of these branches into my own git account:

```
git remote add tempgateway git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git
git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:otheruser/Gateway.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:otheruser/Gateway.git (push)
tempgateway git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git (fetch)
tempgateway git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git (push)
```

But it appears at the moment that ssh authentication fails when I try to reach my git repository:

```
git remote show tempgateway
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So I generate ssh keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/tempgateway.id_rsa
ls -l
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser 1675 2014-01-02 15:39 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  399 2014-01-02 15:41 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1768 2014-01-02 16:22 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser 1679 2014-01-02 16:55 tempgateway.id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  401 2014-01-02 16:55 tempgateway.id_rsa.pub
```

Then I add the config file and enter the following:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host tempgateway.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/tempgateway.id_rsa
```

I add to ssh:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add ~/.ssh/tempgateway.id_rsa
```

ssh-add -l

```
2048 cb:cf:15:9d:6d:73:ac:d0:b2:8e:df:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ~/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
2048 cd:f3:f8:2e:8d:53:3e:59:1b:38:68:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ~/.ssh/tempgateway.id_rsa (RSA)
```

Then add the public key for tempgateway to my github account.

To test I've done this all correctly, I did the following check:

```
ssh -T git@tempgateway.github.com
Hi MyUser! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi OtherUser! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Now while I am able to show remotes still for origin, when I try to show remotes for tempgateway I get the following still:

```
git remote show tempgateway
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

git push tempgateway origin/master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Why am I able to ssh into that git repository, but I cannot show the origin or push to it?

Comment: What is the result of running `git ls-remote git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git`?

Comment: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: That suggests you need to grant access to 'MyUser' to the repository in Github.

Comment: Actually there are two MyUser. One is the actual MyUser of the github account where the repository is hosted. And the other myuser is just an ubuntu user role.

Comment: Sorry I mean on github.com, rather than on the server. You can authenticate OK with Github, so it suggests a permissions issue with that user accessing that repository.

Comment: Yes Github user permissions. Log in to github.com and confirm repository has the MyUser user inside a team with access

Comment: @StigM the MyUser is the owner of the git repository.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44362/discussion-between-stigm-and-johnmerlino)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SSH access is working, as you have shown it to be, then I would ensure the new remote repo is initialized (or copied) properly. If not, then git will not recognise it as a repo.

Edit:

Sorry, I didn't notice you are using github. You won't need to bother with the above then.

But I did notice that in using different SSH key pairs for the two accounts, you haven't made use of `tempgateway.github.com` when you ran the config commands in setting up the new remote repository. Try editing .git/config and using the new SSH identity name you created in the remote URL.

The output of the `git remote -v` command should probably be more like

```
tempgateway git@tempgateway.github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git (fetch)
tempgateway git@tempgateway.github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git (push)
```

than

```
tempgateway git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git (fetch)
tempgateway git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git (push)
```

Comment: But I am not trying to initialize this with files. I am trying to push an existing repository

Comment: To answer your question, I ran "git remote add tempgateway git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git"

Comment: And then I ran "git remote -v" which gave me this:
origin  git@github.com:otheruser/Gateway.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:otheruser/Gateway.git (push)
tempgateway git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git (fetch)
tempgateway git@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git (push)

Comment: Please check that you are indeed using your new key pair. I have edited my reply to expand on this.

Comment: I see what you are saying. How can I make it to be "git@tempgateway.github.com" rather than "git@github.com"

Comment: You could try rerunning the original command to set the remote url again, or you can just edit the .git/config file in your main dir. The command are just a convenience for writing to this config file.

Comment: So you mean I should have ran this: git remote add tempgateway git@tempgateway.github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git but since I didn't I have to edit the .git/config file to have this: url = git@tempgateway.@github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git

Comment: Yes, just about. If you had run the command you indicated, then git/ssh should use you new key pair, and the .git/config should have the new remote url as  url = git@tempgateway.github.com:myuser/TemporaryGateway.git